# Passing a Class as parameter and instantiating an object using this class

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is this possible, I searched the net and found no answer to this. My senior also said that this is not possible.

I'm trying to add this as a category, so I want to extract 4 types of objects out of it, all of them uses the same code, it's just the classes that differ so I thought of this:

```
- (NSDictionary *) getObjectsOfClass:(Class)class
{

    NSMutableDictionary *objDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:class]) {

            /*
            Is there a way to do this?
            class *label = (class *)obj;

            */


        }
    }];

    return objDict;
}
```

So is there a way to make this work? It's ugly to see 4 functions with almost the same codes, you agree right?

Comment: There's no way to tell at compile time what that is going to be, but why do you have to? What is the actual code you're wanting to run?

Comment: Why you need to cast those objects ?

Comment: Imagine the line  class *label = (class *)obj, change the "class" to four different classes like uilabel,uitextfield etc, you will need four functions to do this right? I want it to be dynamic and only 1 function

Comment: @BryanPosas I see that you have plenty of answers already.Just a little something, probably misspelled : you don't need pointer `*` after the BOOL in your block. http://nshipster.com/bool/ this is very nice post about the boolean types

Comment: @wootage, ah no, that is objective c native, it's a reference inside of the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock to tell it to stop looping by using *stop = true ;)

Comment: @BryanPosas , my appologies.It is always nice to learn something new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of you said "But I'm adding it to uiview, to get the textfields, labels, pickerviews etc, so that I can just call [self.view getObjectsOfClass:[UILabel class]"

For this code

```
  [self.view getObjectsOfClass:[UILabel class]];
```

it will return all its UILabel immediate children of it.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getObjectsOfClass:(Class)class
{

    NSMutableArray *objArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


        // All visible things are inherited from UIView. Tag property is belongs to UIView
        // UILabel are inherited from UIView
        if ([self isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && [obj isKindOfClass:class]) {

            UIView *aView = (UIView*)obj;

            if (aView.tag == 100) {

                //This is the view with tag 100

            }

            [objArray addObject:obj];


        }
    }];

    return objArray;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is my current code which I haven't tested yet, how would I be able to check the obj's tag property? This is the reason why I need to cast it to the passed parameter first.

Comment: I am still not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but once you have your objects in the array, if all you need to do is access the tag property then you can assign it via a cast to a `UIView *` variable - `UIView` is the root class of all of the classes you are looking at and that is where the `tag` property is defined

Comment: @BryanPosas i have updated the answer. verify it for your question

Answer (score 4):

What about passing class name as string & creating object out of it. May be like this

```
    -(NSArray *)arrayOfObjectsForClass:(NSString *)className{

        NSMutableArray *objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        CGFloat yAxis = 10;
        for(int i =0;  i<5; i++){
           id object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yAxis, 100, 50)];
           [object setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i+1]];
           [objectArray addObject:object];
           yAxis+= 60;
         }

       return objectArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate your `class` argument like this:

```
id newInstance = [class new];
```

What you cannot syntactically do is using `class *` as a way to tell the compiler which type your local variable is. But this is also not required, thanks to Objective C dynamics typing capabilities.

In other words, there is not reason to cast to `class` (and you cannot do that; `class` is only known at runtime, casting has effect at compile time).

EDIT:

If you know a base class common to all of your classes, e.g. `UIView`, then you could do:

```
UIView* newInstance = obj;
```

then access its properties, e.g.:

```
if (newInstance.tag ==…)
```

Or you could use message sending instead of properties and do:

```
if ([obj tag] == ...)
```

Comment: then after this I can use newInstance *lbl = (newInstance *)obj?

Comment: You can simply do: `lbl = newInstance;`, but I am not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the obj's tag property, you can look at Mr. Vijay-apple-dev's answer below, that is how my current code really looks like, I need to cast it first to make the object recognize that is has tag property

Comment: Please, see my edit. You either cast to `UIView` or you send the object a message instead of accessing a property.

Answer (score 2):

If all of them are derived from a common base class, you can cast them into that common base class. If few functions are not available then create a category of that common base class and add those common functions into it. This will allow you to have single code block rather than 4 different one.

Comment: But I'm adding it to uiview, to get the textfields, labels, pickerviews etc, so that I can just call [self.view getObjectsOfClass:[UILabel class]

Comment: In that case you can directly or ( || ) the if condition statement.